# GNUMake: Missing separator issue in makefile targer

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here is my Makefile snippet.

```
1. $(DIR_REL64)/%: $(SHIFT_BINDIR64)/%
2.  $(copy_file)
3.ifneq ($(TEST),0)
4.ifneq($(LOG),0)
5.  if [ -d $(TGT32)/tools/test/64bit ]; then cp -f $< $(TGT32)/tools/test/64bit; fi
6.else
7.  if [ -d $(TGT64)/tools/test/64bit ]; then cp -f $< $(TGT64)/tools/test/64bit; fi
8.endif 
9.else
10. if [ -d $(TGT64)/bin ]; then cp -f $< $(TGT64)/bin; fi
11.endif
```

I am getting error:

```
GNUmakefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Anything wrong in my makefile rule ? Please help

Comment: `ifneq($(LOG),0)` --> `ifneq ($(LOG),0)`?  Note the extra space between the `ifneq` and the opening `(`.

Answer (score 0):

Every line in the rule needs to be tab indented (no spaces). Your indentations appear to be mixed (though I can't tell 100% from the pasted code).

Also you should try not to mix make and bash syntax where you can avoid it. For example you can do.

There may also be some extra spaces at the ends of some of the lines (I can't tell from here) but makesure there is no white spaces at the ends.

I would re-write it line-by-line starting with just:

```
$(DIR_REL64)/%: $(SHIFT_BINDIR64)/%
    $(copy_file)
```

Where $(copy_file) is tab indented. Make sure that works and then add the next bit.